# Converting String to Integer (or other primitive) after pulling HTML with JSoup

Tags: java, type-conversion

New to programming. Trying to convert a string to a integer.  The string has been retrieved from a website using JSoup.  Haven't read anything that has helped.

The lines labeled below 2 & 3 are the issue.  I can print these lines out as text, but not once I've added Integer.parseInt().  I think the issue is related to getting rid of the white space, but thought the code used would do that.

Assuming 's' below is the letter "A", the output would be as follows (clearly only line 1 is printing):

6,981,000

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class IncomeStatement {
String grossRevenue = "Total Revenue";

public IncomeStatement(String s) { 
    String incomeStatementURL = ("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s="+s+"+Income+Statement&annual"); 
    String incomeStatementTableName = "table.yfnc_tabledata1";

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(incomeStatementURL).get(); 
        Elements table = doc.select(incomeStatementTableName);
        Elements row = table.select("tr");
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        for (int j = 0; j < tds.size(); j++) {
            if(tds.get(j).text().equals(grossRevenue)) {
            /*1*/System.out.println(tds.get(j+1).text());
            /*2*/System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tds.get(j+1).text().replaceAll(",","").trim()));
            /*3*/System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tds.get(j+1).text().replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("\\s+","")));
            }                   
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `j + 1` you should stop one sooner in your `for` loop test of `j`. I suggest you test `grossRevenue.equals()` using a [Yoda Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). And, you could use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to split on `,` (and optional white space) and then iterate the comma separated values with something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < tds.size() - 1; j++) {
    if (grossRevenue.equals(tds.get(j).text()) {
        for (String value : tds.get(j + 1).text().split(",\\s*")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(value.trim()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Good idea(s).  The `grossRevenue.equals()` makes a lot of sense.  ....Where can I get a better understanding of how you came to the `",\\s*"`?  I don't see anything in the Java documentation under split.

Comment: Also, when using the code you posted, why does it trim the ending zeros? I'm guess that will be answered once I figure out the `",\\s*"`?

Comment: @Nikolas `",\\s*"` is a regular expression of three parts. The third part makes the second optional (it's the `*`), the second part is the predefined class from [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\s` (you have to escape the back-slash in your code) and the first part is a literal comma.